# How to run query based on information from specific customer?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that is tabular and displays all of the information from my main table. I want to be able to double click on a record (if possible a record selector), then run a query based on the specific values for that unique customer.

At the moment, I am able to click on a record selector and run the generic query. But, I want to be able to make that query different depending on which user is clicked. Here is the code I have for running the query based on double clicking on a record selector.

```
    Private Sub Form_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
      DoCmd.OpenQuery "contribution"
    End Sub
```

For example, if the Product Number is 01, and the check date is 06/18/13 for Customer1, I want to use this information for the criteria in my query.

I'm really just not sure if you can run a query based on information from a record selector. If not, how else could I go about this? I just started learing VBA in the past week so I'm a novice, but I have other coding experience so I'm learning pretty quick. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just opening the query itself, I recommend using the query as the record source for a form.  This gives you much greater flexibility over the appearance & content.

To open the form, try [DoCmd.OpenForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820845.aspx).  This allows you to include Where conditions and Filters to get the specific record you want.  The link includes examples (and if that isn't enough, just google for more or ask here).

#### Edit

Using your case as an example, let's call your main form `FrmA` and your query results `FrmB`. In both of your record sources (which can be tables or queries), your product number is called `ProdNum` and the check date is `CheckDate` (They don't have to be called the same thing in both sources, but I'm trying to keep it simple)

In FrmA, add a command button to the Detail section.  This command button will have a Click event.  Try this code:

```
  DoCmd.OpenForm "FrmB",,,
      "[ProdNum]=" & Me.ProdNum & 
      " and [CheckDate]=#" & Me.CheckDate & "#"
```

In this code, I added the line breaks for readability (you should take those out).  Also, I'm assuming the ProdNum field is a number type and the CheckDate field is of type Date which is why I'm surrounding it in # signs. The `Me.ProdNum` is referring to the field value in `FrmA` and is passing that value as a Where condition to FrmB.

Comment: Thanks for helping! But the query I want to run is based on a different table so just displaying the specific data in a form won't exactly work.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes it will. These are 2 different forms with different record sources.  One form just opens the other. (Or if you want to display your query results as an embedded subform, then the same concepts still apply.)

Comment: There is 1 form that displays all of the records. I want to click on one of the records and run a query that is based on the criteria from the record I clicked on. The query is based on another table I have.

Comment: This is a common task.  I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I just posted an answer to my own question so I could have more room to type. Not really sure how to use this question/answer format yet haha.